# Converting Angular 1 to Angular 2 ngInit function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In angular1, we call the function ng-init based on ng-if condition. The following code represents If first div match with date && time then it will check the second condition, checked or not checked. If checked then it's automatically call play() function and if it's not check then call the pause function.

```
<div ng-if="ramadan.date === date && ramadan.time === clock">
  <div ng-if="ramadan.checked" ng-init="play()"></div>
  <div ng-if="!ramadan.checked" ng-init="pause()"></div>
</div>
```

I want to convert this code by angular2 typescript. Is there any way to automatically call the function based on condition in angular 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `ng-init` in Angular2. You can easily create such a directive yourself though.

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngInit]'
})
export class NgInit {
    @Input() ngInit;
    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.ngInit) {
            this.ngInit();
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
<div *ngIf="ramadan.date === date && ramadan.time === clock">
  <div *ngIf="ramadan.checked" [ngInit]="play"></div>
  <div *ngIf="!ramadan.checked" [ngInit]="pause"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the way that works to call ngInit function using directive. But in my case it works differently. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "ln my case it works differently", how?

Comment: I used directive that's okay but based on condition it working that's it.

Comment: When the first `*ngIf` becomes true, `play()` is called, otherwise `pause()`. I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: Yes!! some of study about angular 2 directive then I write these steps. Just reading - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html .Thanks!! your direction is correct.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can this be used to just assign value to a local variable and not calling a function?

Comment: You can use an output `@Output() init = new EventEmitter()` that emits an event in `ngOnInit() { this.init.emit(null); }` and use it like `<div ngInit (init)="xxx = 'abc'">` where `xxx` is a field on the current component. You can't initialize template variables though. You could add `exportAs: 'ngInit'` to `@Directive(...)` though and then use it like `<div ngInit #myTmp="ngInit" (change)="myTmp.xxx = 'abc'"` and then read it like `{{myTmp.xxx}}`. This way `xxx` is added to the `NgInit` directive instance.

Comment: how to send parameters for play function ex: play(i)

Comment: You can add additional `@Input()`s or assign a closure to a field like `play = () => { this._play(this.a, this.b); };`

Comment: This is running for every change detection inside an ngFor, not just on init. Any help with that? I even have trackby in my ngFor, so i thought it shouldnt re render for every change.

Comment: It's a hack because there is no such thing as `ng-init` in Angular 2+. You can add an `if(...)` to the code above to do nothing after the first initialization.

Answer (score 6):

Working code,

**Custom directive:**

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myCondition]' })

export class ngInitDirective {
  constructor() { }


  @Input() set myCondition(condition: boolean) {
    if (!condition) {
      console.log("hello")
    } else {
      console.log("hi")
    }
  }
}
```

In template:

```
<ion-label *ngIf="setting1.date === current_date && setting1.time === current_time">
          <div *myCondition="setting1.checked === condition" >Play</div>
          <div *myCondition="!setting1.checked === !condition">pause</div>
      </ion-label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngOnInit method in your component class but remember to implements the **OnInit** interface.

Here's an example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ramadan',
  template: `<div>Ramadan</div>`
})
class Ramadan implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.play();
  }
}
```

You can fin more about ngOnInit [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html).