# angular's ng-init alternative in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the alternative of `ng-init="myText='Hello World!'"` in Angular 2 to add in the template, not in the component

```
 <div ng-app="" ng-init="myText='Hello World!'">
```

the alternative in Angular 2

Comment: Above one is angular1 sample. i am expecting the alternative in angular2

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your purpose in using `ng-init` in Angular2?

Comment: Expecting something like this  *ngOnInit = "checkCategoryStart = checkCategoryStart != row.category && row.category"

Comment: i am using inside the *ngFor

Comment: I don't think there's something like `ng-init` on Angular2. Anyway you can do this kind of thing on component instead of template.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a directive

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'ngInit',
  exportAs: 'ngInit'
}) 
export class NgInit {
  @Input() values: any = {};

  @Input() ngInit;
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.ngInit) { this.ngInit(); }
  }  
}
```

you can use it to pass a function to be called like

```ts
<div [ngInit]="doSomething"
```

or to make values available

```ts
<div ngInit [values]="{a: 'a', b: 'b'}" #ngInit="ngInit">
  <button (click)="clickHandler(ngInit.values.a)">click me</button>
</div>
```

- `ngInit` addes the directive
- `[values]="{a: 'a', b: 'b'}"` sets some initial values
- `#ngInit="ngInit"` creates a reference for later use
- `ngInit.values.a` reads the `a` value from the created reference.

See also [Converting Angular 1 to Angular 2 ngInit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753698/converting-angular-1-to-angular-2-nginit-function/37753794#37753794)

Comment: here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HmWHjM8wa8gIhuClGdO2?p=preview .  in almost all cases if you are looking at this you should probably ```ng g component  youNeedAComponent```   +1 for exportAs example.

Comment: nice hack. :) (y)

Comment: How about passing a parm in method like `<div [ngInit]="doSomething(parm)"`? How should it be handled in the custom directive?

Comment: Binding to functions is usually a bad idea, because it will be called every time change detection runs. Besides that I don't understand your question. There shouldn't be any need to handle it in a special way.

Comment: @Rishi don't know what you mean. Why would it not work with `*ngFor`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer actually I tried passing it to another component and I changed the value from there, which is not working. In my case I have emitted an event to update in the parent scope.
[link](https://angular-5-tutorial-5unhre.stackblitz.io)

Comment: @Rishi the link only shows the running app, not the source. please use the share button to create a share link.

Comment: Look down for the answer with the Output() and EventEmitter. This is the correct way to do it because passing FN as a reference will make you lose the `this` reference unless using fat arrow syntax. Also, using the Output() syntaxt let you pass parameters on the FN call.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach is by using the [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#declaring-input-and-output-properties) decorator and [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter):

```
import {Directive, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngInit]'
})
export class NgInitDirective implements OnInit {

    @Output()
    ngInit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ngInit.emit();
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
<div *ngIf="condition" (ngInit)="initialize()">  ... </div>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nginit-using-output?file=src%2Fapp%2Fng-init.directive.ts)

Comment: Clean solution!

Answer (score 5):

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngxInit]',
})
export class NgxInitDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  @Input() set ngxInit(val: any) {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {ngxInit: val});
  }
}
```

a value expression is set via `*ngxInit` and published using `as` micro-syntax:

```html
<div *ngxInit="3 * i + j as idx">{{idx}}</div>
```

published as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-init

Comment: Amazing ! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @user2732686 please send an issue at https://github.com/amitport/ngx-init/issues

Answer (score 4):

You do not always need a custom directive for this. 
If you're okay with your function being called more than once, you can simple do:

`<input #input [attr.init]="resizeInput(input)"/>`

The word "init" there is completely arbitrary. The downside is yourInitFunction will get called on every digest cycle.

Note, if you return anything from your function this will add an attribute called "init" to your element with the returned value. If you return `undefined`, it will not add the attribute.

This is normally a non-issue, just keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by using **OnInit** Life Cycle hook as below,

1. Import OnInit from core library

   ```
   import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
   ```
2. Implement it to your component class

   ```
   export class App  implements OnInit {

   }
   ```
3. Implement the ngOnInit method

   ```
    ngOnInit(){
       this.myText='Hello World!'

      }
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/OKiKAy1V4vMxljaV6NGt?p=preview)**

Comment: Note that the implements clause is completely optional as is the import of `OnInit`.

Comment: Create a new scoped variable for each item inside ngFor

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that initialization should go into the ngOnInit life-cycle hook, it should also be noted that you can use the constructor of the component to initialize class members. In your simple example, you could even use the member declaration to set the variable, e.g.:

```
@Component({ template: '<div>{{myText}}</div>' })
export class MyComponent {
    myText = 'Hello World!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little Update! 
In the latest versions of Angular this will not work:

```
@Directive({
 selector: 'ngInit',
 exportAs: 'ngInit'
})
```

you should use '[]':

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[ngInit]',
   exportAs: 'ngInit'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible improvement over Günter's answer:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'ngInit',
  exportAs: 'ngInit'
}) 
export class NgInit {
  @Input() ngInit: () => any;
  ngOnInit() {
    if(typeof this.ngInit === 'function') { 
        this.ngInit(); 
    } else {
        // preventing re-evaluation (described below)
        throw 'something';
    }
  }  
}
```

And then use higher-order functions for passing in data, like so:

```
// component.ts
myInitFunction(info) {
  // returns another function
  return () => console.log(info);
}
```

If you use a higher-order function like this, you also don't need to worry about what `this` is inside of `myInitFunction` since an arrow function is really what is passed.

Use the directive like so:

```
// component.html
<another-component #ref></another-component>
<div [ngInit]="myInitFunction(ref)"></div>
```

If you were to try and create a directive that doesn't pass in a function as the input in the manner described here, you run the risk of infinite loops. For example, you'd get that if you whole directive was simply evaluating the expression you gave it.

This is what would happen if your `myInitFunction` method didn't return another function (and your HTML was the same as above). You'd console out, return undefined, and then change detection would re-evaluate it, consoling out over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly easy fix for this problem using the `data` attribute.
In my example, i just use it to show, but a toggle or whatever is possible using the same method obviously.

```
<div data-expand="false" #expandWrap>
  <span *ngIf="expandWrap.dataset.expand == 'false'">
    {{'Test expand without..'}}
    <span (click)="expandWrap.dataset.expand = 'true'">more</span>
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="expandWrap.dataset.expand == 'true'">
       {{'Test expand with more text because now we are expanded!'}}
  </span>
</div>
```

I made [a small demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expand-template-init?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.html) on how this works

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[onInit]'
})
export class OnInitDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() onInit = new EventEmitter<void>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onInit.emit();
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```
<div (onInit)="doSomeStuff(someValue)"></div>
```