# Declare variable in custom template in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can I declare variable that isn't coming from parent component? In this example rowData comes from p-column but I need to declare another variable.

```
<p-column *ngFor="let h of header">
    <template let-ms="rowData" pTemplate="body" let-m="getMetricByName(ms.metrics, h)">
                {{m.name}} //for example
    </template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to declare variables in the template.

See also [angular's ng-init alternative in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866741/angulars-ng-init-alternative-in-angular-2/41868229#41868229)

This issue seems related https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15020