# how to set a variable value inside of a ionic template?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to declare a variable and set a value in my IONIC app Template file. It's actually working like angular template. The variable may used singly or in a foreach iteration. I already got some solution but solutions are not working.
I tried as following...

```
{{flag = true; ""}}
```

another is using **ng-init**..

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" ng-init="myVariable = 'something...'">
  {{myVariable}}
  ...
</div>
```

So, I can not set variable and it's value in ionic template. Please give me a solution which is actually working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866741/angulars-ng-init-alternative-in-angular-2

Comment: angularjs (v1) has ng-init not angular 2+

Comment: why dont you do it in component in ngOnInit()