# How do I implement ngInit in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-loopback, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am trying to implement [ngInit] in angular 8 code as said in this link [ConvertingAngular1To2ngInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753698/converting-angular-1-to-angular-2-nginit-function/37753794#37753794)
and it almost worked for me but the problem is it execute more than one time and in some case it go in infinite loop or almost infinite and it crash my page entirely. 
so i tried to put the function in the html as `{{functionName(5)}}` and it executed multiple either even if i am putting it in `*ngIf` directive. 
i even started new project and just put the function in html at least it executed four time
i searched a lot for this problem and got stuck in angular life cycle hooks but understood nothing.

Comment: When you call a method directly in the template, it will run every time Angular Change Detection runs. Thats why you will see it called multiple times. The question is, do you need to implement such functionality? What are you trying to achieve, there may be another way

Comment: i want to implement a directive like [ngInit] and it happen also with it. executed multiple time

Comment: you can use some like `*ngIf="variable && yourFunction()"`. So only when variable is true execute the function